# Sync post between Facebook Group and Website using Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I have a website and a very active Facebook group.

I need a Two way sync between the Website and the Facebook Group.This means anything posted on the website should be automatically posted on my Facebook group and anything posted on my Facebook Group should be posted on my website.

At the moment i have figured out the way to post from my website using the graph api.

My question is how do i do the vice versa i.e whenever a post gets posted on my website i automatically update it on my website.

Is there a api to do this ,some kind of push from facebook or is continuous polling only way ?

Comment: Check this out : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27757178/facebook-push-notification

Comment: have you done this task? @abhishek-ranjan